# How to make notification box float in the center

Tags: css

Using Bulma css framework, I try to make the notification box popup at about the center of the page, without interrupting existing data (it is a notification that pops for 3 seconds and then it should disappear). For example: 2 images on top of each other(snippet 1), and I want the notification box to float on top of them without pushing any content(snippet 2)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notification is-primary">
    <button class="delete"></button> Primar lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor. <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut, porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla. Nullam
    gravida purus diam, et dictum <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position it absolute, so it gets out of the document flow then the known trick `top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply give the notification **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)** along with a **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** which is higher than the element you want it to sit on top of (`1` will likely work fine):

```css
.notification.is-primary {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notification is-primary">
    <button class="delete"></button> Primar lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor. <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut, porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla. Nullam
    gravida purus diam, et dictum <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="level main">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a CSS rule like:

```
.top-of-the-world{
   position: absolute !important;
   z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

That way I do not alter Bulma's rules.

Then I added the class *top-of-the-world* to my *notification*

```
.notification.top-of-the-world
```